# Pgloader -- How to load constant while using load csv

Tags: csv, constants, pgloader

I am using pgloader to load file into Tables.
I need to load constant (ie, field not provided by the csv) but I do not succeed.

my configuration looks like :

```
LOAD CSV  
  FROM './file.csv'
  HAVING FIELDS
  (a, b, c)
INTO postgresql:///pgloader?my_table
  TARGET COLUMNS
  (
    a
    ,b   
    ,c  
    ,Src
  )
  WITH
    skip header = 0,  
    fields optionally enclosed by '"',  
    fields escaped by double-quote,  
    fields terminated by ';'  
;
```

and I need to put 'SRC' static value into the field my_table.Src.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

regards,

--
Julien

Comment: Add a line in your  import script,  `UPDATE my_table SET constant_field='the constant value';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the 'using' instruction

```
LOAD CSV  
  FROM './file.csv'
  HAVING FIELDS
  (a, b, c)
INTO postgresql:///pgloader?my_table
  TARGET COLUMNS
  (
    a,
    b,   
    c,  
    Src text using "SRC"
  )
  WITH
    skip header = 0,  
    fields optionally enclosed by '"',  
    fields escaped by double-quote,  
    fields terminated by ';'  
;
```

Comment: can be variabilized using templating : 
```Src text using "{{VAR_SRC}}"```